# C# TcpClient and node.js 'net' module use Ipv4 only

Tags: c#, node.js, tcpclient, ipv4

I am connected to a node.js server with a C# TcpClient:

```
 TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
           tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8000);
```

Node.js code:

```
var connectedClients = [];
var tcp_server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

   var newClient = socket.address();
   connectedClients[newClient.address].push(newClient);
});

tcp_server.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log("tcp server listening");
});
```

However the `socket.adress` is IPv6, but I need it in IPv4 format. Some simple solution to force the `TcpClient` using IPv4? `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` didn't work.

Comment: Isn't this a node question, not a C# question?